# jquery - load function does not correctly work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I built a function that waits for an image to load and then execute some other functions. In Fierfox it always works in Chrome it sometimes does not work. It seems that it stucks and does not continue. What part is bad? I think because the image is loaded the load function is not triggered:

jQuery

```
$("#myImages").load(function () {
    var a = $("#visual").find('img').width();
    var b = $("#visual").find('img').height();
    var c = (a - 0.6 * a);
    $("#box").css("height", b).css("width", (500 - c));
    $("#loading_screen").fadeOut();
    setTimeout(startAnimation, 800);
}).attr('src', 'big_image.png');
```

Comment: Are you using it in document.ready?

Comment: I'm loading it at the end of the body with an js iffi

Comment: It'd be good if you could put up a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I would suggest wrapping the code in `$(document).ready(function() {}`.   This will help ensure that the DOM is ready for the jQuery function to run.

Comment: I think because the image is loaded the load function is not triggered

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the entire thing in an on ready function, like this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#myImages").load(function () {
    var a = $("#visual").find('img').width();
    var b = $("#visual").find('img').height();
    var c = (a - 0.6 * a);
    $("#box").css("height", b).css("width", (500 - c));
    $("#loading_screen").fadeOut();
    setTimeout(startAnimation, 800);
}).attr('src', 'big_image.png');
});
```

This way the function won't try to run before the page is actually ready for it.

Comment: I did so, but it does not fix the bug

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).bind('load', function(){
   //Page loaded
});
```